# optimize some CG code generated by likethought opacity?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

how can I write this ios code snippet so that it doesn't have any sqrt and even better no *'s and /'s? (this is from code generated by likethought opacity) (or is it even necessary to do that type of optimization here? i'm just afraid this code will be called a lot of times as each frame will contain many sprites and this will happen each time any of those frames are drawn, the way it's written right now..)

```
...
    CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, kmy_exampleWidth, kmy_exampleHeight);
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
    transform = CGContextGetUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform(context);
...

    resolution = sqrtf(fabsf(transform.a * transform.d - transform.b * transform.c)) * 0.5f * (bounds.size.width / imageBounds.size.width + bounds.size.height / imageBounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt those will be an issue. Go ahead and get your code working right, then if you have performance problems use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to find your bottleneck. If these functions do wind up taking a long time, see if it's computing values every frame that are always the same and cache those instead of reevaluating them. (Glancing at the code above, my guess is the transform matrix is always going to be the same [and the determinant computation sqrtf(fabs(t.a*t.d-t.b*t.c)) will either be just 1 or 2, depending on whether it's a retina display or not] and if the imageBounds and the view bounds don't change, resolution won't change. But without seeing what context this code is in, this is just a guess.)